# How to change boot device on vm installed on Citrix Xen Server to DVD

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, boot

I have installed Centos 6 on my new Xen Server (XenServer release 6.2.0-70446c). Everything went smooth. System is working fine but now I want to change boot device on that VM to boot from DVD (iso from nfs storage) But in properties there is only Hard Disk option... I was looking for adding some new DVD device but didn't  find where (On Vmware it's very simple and maybe here to but I was searching quite long time and it's became frustrating )... It's strange to me because when I was creating VM for Centos system had to start from DVD and everything went well and without problems but now when I wan't to change boot order I can't (don't know how)
[image]

What I do wrong ... because I don't believe that it is impossible on Xen.
How to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess your CentOS 6 instance is running in `paravirtualized` mode and such behavior is just a side effect of it. To access virtual CD/DVD drive, you need to start the instance  in `recovery mode`. From `VM` menu, select `Start/Shut down` and `Start in recovery mode`. This

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue as B14D3 using the same version of Xenserver and VMs with Centos 6 and 7. I need to resize the file system using gparted, to accomplish that I need to boot from the live dvd.

I can't find the "Start in recovery mode" as referenced on the answer above. I guess it only works with Ubuntu or another OS.

I've found the solution for this problem: [xenlens.com Boot a guest VM from CD or DVD in XenServer](http://www.xenlens.com/boot-a-guest-vm-from-cd-or-dvd-in-xenserver/)

Which is basically executing this command in any of the hosts of the pool:

```
xe vm-param-set HVM-boot-policy="BIOS order" uuid=[uuid of your vm]
```

You can find the uuid of your vm in the "VM general properties" of each VM. Find the row where it says "UUID"

After running the command you will see the boot options (I tried to include an screen shot but I don't have enough reputation)

I hope it helps.

Philippe.

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippe, I had this issue with the "Boot Options" not displayed in some VMs (I think the ones I created from a snapshot of a VM), your hint worked perfectly!